# ¿Como recuperar conversión informaciones con JavaScript en una google spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheets

Quiero escribir en una funcion javascript para una google Spreadsheet que actualiza la conversión del dólar australiano del euro cada vez que hago clic en un botón
Sin embargo, no sé dónde y cómo obtener dicha información con JavaScript y Google SPreadsheets.

Por lo momento tengo :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Update prices', 'updatePrices')
      .addToUi();
}

function updatePrices() {
  Browser.msgBox("Update prices !");
  var cell=selection.getCell(1,1);
  cell.setValue(1,50067526); // valor el 18 de Octubre. Necesito cambiarlo con la valor actualizada
}
```

Por ejemplo necesito recuperar el valor del euro del dólar canadiense
He visto que [fixer.io](http://fixer.io/) puede ayudarme con esta búsqueda :

```
http://api.fixer.io/latest
```

Muestra el resultado de una consulta y parece que dentre de todos los otras monedas hay el  dólar canadiense. ¿Como puedo recuperarlo y ponerlo en el codigo arriba ?

Comment: Te refieres a la informacion del valor de conversion? Seguramente haya alguna api que retorne a cuanto està la equivalencia de cada moneda, de manera actualizada.

Comment: @lois6b Si. Pero nunca hice una llamada de api en ningún idioma

Comment: Bueno, SOes es para aprender hahah busca la existencia de alguna, intenta llamar a la api y si tienes problemas pregunta aqui :P Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) para obtener la respuesta HTTP de una URL, que en el caso de http://api.fixer.io/latest devuelve un cadena de texto con estructura de un objeto JSON.

Luego usa JSON.parse(string) para convertir la cadena de texto en un objeto JSON.

Por último, extrae el elemento deseado. Ejemplo:

```
function unaFuncion() {
  var elResultado = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://api.fixer.io/latest"); 
  var elObjeto = JSON.parse(elResultado);
  Logger.log(elObjeto.rates["AUD"]);
}
```